# Chef not executing "mount" on first bootstrap

Tags: debian, chef-infra, cloud-init, s3fs

I am trying to mount s3fs using chef. I could not get the mounts resource to work for s3fs and the vendor cookbook for s3fs wants to name the mount something different than what we want to name it (our s3 buckets have "." in the name).

So I manually created the fstab record and run a "mount" command to mount it. However the mount is not running. There are no errors and the chef log file says it executed the block.

```
bash 'mount_s3fs' do
  code <<-EOF 
  mount -a
  EOF
  user 'root'
  not_if "df -kh | grep s3fs -q"
end
```

Here is what gets printed to the log file

```
[2016-12-29T21:29:02+00:00] INFO: Processing bash[mount_s3fs] action run (cookbook::recipe line 66)
[2016-12-29T21:29:03+00:00] INFO: bash[mount_s3fs] ran successfully
```

If I run the recipe a second time it mounts just fine. If I add the recipe after bootstrap it runs fine. I am incredibly perplexed. As this behavior is only seen at bootstrap.

I am running on chef 12.12.15 on Debian Jessie 8.4 in AWS.

Comment: Looks like this is not a chef issue after all. Adding mount -a to the user-data script also does not mount s3fs.

Comment: Looks like a problem with cloud-init, making any changes to mount(s) in /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg seems to trigger this

Comment: Here is what I added to the clould.cfg
    mounts:
     - [ephemeral0, null]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after hours and hours of troubleshooting, I think that the issue is with Debian itself. If I run this same script with a Debian 8.0 AMI it works fine, If I go up to a 8.4 or higher image it doesn't work. I did not test with an 8.1, 8.2 or 8.3 because, well, I am tired of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't appear to be related to Chef, you should probably fix your recipe code to use a `mount` resource instead.

Comment: The mount did not work either. Same results. Not mounted on bootstrap, no errors thrown:

Comment: `[2016-12-30T21:54:15+00:00] INFO: Processing mount[/mnt/s3backup] action mount (a5y-solr-cloud::s3fs_backup_directory line 56)
[2016-12-30T21:54:15+00:00] DEBUG: Providers for generic mount resource enabled on node include: [Chef::Provider::Mount::Mount]
[2016-12-30T21:54:15+00:00] DEBUG: Provider for action mount on resource mount[/mnt/s3backup] is Chef::Provider::Mount::Mount
[2016-12-30T21:54:15+00:00] DEBUG: mount[/mnt/s3backup] is mounted at /mnt/s3backup
[2016-12-30T21:54:15+00:00] INFO: mount[/mnt/s3backup] mounted`

Comment: Sounds like Chef is calling the mount commands, might be some other issue?